# CakePHP ORM : Query with a join on the same table with a non-standard association

Tags: php, cakephp, orm, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

I have a very particular use case, and i can't find a clean solution with the ORM. I've searched a lot, and maybe my database model is not correct, I'm not sure.

I use CakePHP 3.8.11.

So, I have a table "MaintenanceTypes" with 3 important fields : id, name, and periodicity. Periodicity (in days) means "this maintenance is to be done every (for instance) 30 days".

Periodicity are like 7 (week), 30 (month), 90 (trimester) and so on.

I also have a table "Operations", they are little unit tests that belongs to a "MaintenanceType" (fields are id, name, maintenance_type_id).

What is special in this case, is that, as a business rule, Operations belonging to a MaintenanceType with a periodicity of 7 days is "included" in **every** MaintenanceType with a greater periodicity; that means that every trimester, you should do every Operations associated directly to the trimester, **but** also every Operations associated with the month, and the week, etc.

In raw SQL it's trivial :slight_smile:

**mt_ref** is the reference MaintenanceType, **mt_inc** are the included MaintenanceTypes (with a lesser periodicity) and finally, every Operations belonging to any of the MaintenanceTypes found.

```sql
    SELECT mt_ref.id, mt_ref.name, mt_ref.periodicity, 
        mt_inc.name, mt_inc.periodicity, o.name 
    FROM maintenance_types mt_ref 
        LEFT JOIN maintenance_types mt_inc 
            ON (mt_inc.periodicity <= mt_ref.periodicity) 
        LEFT JOIN operations o ON (o.maintenance_type_id = mt_inc.id) 
    WHERE mt_ref.id = 3
```

I've tried to declare the association between MaintenanceTypes, but I can't find a way to declare that the association is done on the periodicity field, and, extra points, not on a equality but on a "less or equal".

To add extra difficulties, I use this query for a (very good) JQuery Datatables CakePHP plugin (https://github.com/allanmcarvalho/cakephp-datatables), so I can't simply pass the raw SQL, and I must use the ORM...

I hope this is clear, and that someone could help me on this one !

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt` or `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Comment: Also is it correct that you compare `o` against `mt_inc`, and not `mt_ref`?

Comment: @ndm : I edited the post to include version information. Also, yes, Operations are searched for in mt_inc (included MaintenanceTypes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need query builder instances, then pretty much have two options here that are more or less straightforward, that is either use associations with custom conditions, or manual joins.

### Custom association conditions

With associations you'd probably do something like a self-association with `MaintenanceTypes` with a disabled foreign key and custom conditions, like so in your `MaintenanceTypesTable` class:

```php
$this
    ->hasMany('MaintenanceTypesInc')
    ->setClassName('MaintenanceTypes')
    ->setForeignKey(false)
    ->setConditions(function (
        \Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression $exp,
        \Cake\ORM\Query $query
    ) {
        return $exp->lte(
            $query->identifier('MaintenanceTypesInc.periodicity'),
            $query->identifier('MaintenanceTypes.periodicity')
        );
    });
```

Disabling the foreign key will prevent the ORM from creating the default `A.fk = B.fk` condition when joining in the association. It should be noted that you cannot contain a `hasMany` association with a disabled foreign key, you can only join it in! You could use a `hasOne` or even `belongsTo` association instead, but it would kinda be a lie, as you don't have a 1:1 relationship here (at least as far as I understand it).

Also note that you don't neccesarily have to use a callback with all expressions for the conditions, you could pass the conditions as a `key => value` array with a manually instantiated identifier expression, or even as simple string (the latter however will not be recognized when using automatic identifier quoting):

```php
->setConditions([
    'MaintenanceTypesInc.periodicity <=' =>
        new \Cake\Database\Expression\IdentifierExpression('MaintenanceTypes.periodicity');
]);
```

```php
->setConditions('MaintenanceTypesInc.periodicity <= MaintenanceTypes.periodicity');
```

Assuming you also have an association for `Operations` in your `MaintenanceTypesTable` class, you should be able to join in both, the new association and the `Operations` association via the query builders `*JoinWith()` methods, like this:

```php
$query = $maintenanceTypesTable
    ->find()
    ->select([
        'MaintenanceTypes.id', 'MaintenanceTypes.name', 'MaintenanceTypes.periodicity',
        'MaintenanceTypesInc.name', 'MaintenanceTypesInc.periodicity',
        'Operations.name',
    ])
    ->leftJoinWith('MaintenanceTypesInc.Operations');
```

In the results, the association data will be put under the `_matchingData` key, ie you can obtain it like `$entity->_matchingData->MaintenanceTypesInc` and `$entity->_matchingData->Operations`. If you don't want that, then you need to use aliases for the fields of the associations, like:

```php
->select([
    'MaintenanceTypes.id', 'MaintenanceTypes.name', 'MaintenanceTypes.periodicity',
    'mt_inc_name' => 'MaintenanceTypesInc.name', 'mt_inc_periodicity' => 'MaintenanceTypesInc.periodicity',
    'op_name' => 'Operations.name',
])
```

If you don't want to select all the fields everytime, use a custom finder as in the manual joins example below.

### Manual joins

Using manual joins gives you complete freedom, with the query builders `*Join()` methods you can create whatever joins you like, and you don't have to use possible workarounds with associations.

You can add them in a custom finder for proper reusability, it could look something like this in your `MaintenanceTypesTable` class:

```php
public function findWithIncludedMaintenanceTypes(\Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $options)
{
    return $query
        ->select(/* ... */)
        ->leftJoin(
            ['MaintenanceTypesInc' => 'maintenance_types'],
            function (
                \Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression $exp,
                \Cake\ORM\Query $query
            ) {
                return $exp->lte(
                    $query->identifier('MaintenanceTypesInc.periodicity'),
                    $query->identifier('MaintenanceTypes.periodicity')
                );
            }
        )
        ->leftJoin(
            ['Operations' => 'operations'],
            function (
                \Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression $exp,
                \Cake\ORM\Query $query
            ) {
                return $exp->equalFields(
                    'Operations.maintenance_type_id ',
                    'MaintenanceTypesInc.id'
                );
            }
        );
}
```

Then you simply use the finder wherever you need it, like this:

```php
$query = $maintenanceTypesTable
    ->find('withIncludedMaintenanceTypes');
```

Note that just like in the associations example, you can use string or array conditions for the custom joins too.

### See also

- [Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Associations - Linking Tables Together](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/associations.html)
- [Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Loading Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/query-builder.html#loading-associations)
- [Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Loading Associations > Using leftJoinWith](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-leftjoinwith)
- [Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Loading Associations > Adding Joins](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-joins)
- [Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Using Finders to Load Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-finders-to-load-data)
- [Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Custom Finder Methods](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-finder-methods)

Comment: I've tried the first solution, but CakePHP told me there isn't any association between MaintenanceTypesInc and Operations, and I did not insist because the second one, with the finder, is a lot better IMHO (I find it more clear), and it worked exactly as i expected !